# Convert VAR output in Real values

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I got some outputs from my VAR model in R, but I wonder how to convert the output values to "real ones" since I differentiated some data inputs and applied a log operations.

For example:

```
 WTI <- diff(log(data[,"WTI"]))
 US_TOTAL_OIL_STOCKS <- diff(log(data[,"US_TOTAL_OIL_STOCKS"]))
 US_LIQ_PETR_STOCKS <- diff(log(data[,"US_LIQ_PETR_STOCKS"]))
 US_OIL_PROD <- diff(log(data[,"US_OIL_PROD"]))
 US_WINTER_DEGREE_DAYS <- diff(log(data[,"US_WINTER_DEGREE_DAYS"]))
 ETHYLENE_SPOT_PIPELINE_CIF_WEST_EUROPE <-  diff(log(data[,"ETHYLENE_SPOT_PIPELINE_CIF_WEST_EUROPE"]))
```

and when I get the following predicted outputs:

```
       $ETHYLENE_SPOT_PIPELINE_CIF_WEST_EUROPE
           fcst       lower      upper         CI
   [1,]  6.066585e-02 -0.02692062 0.14825232 0.08758647
   [2,]  4.301007e-02 -0.06308035 0.14910049 0.10609042
```

I would like to convert them to original metric. In that case, for "USD/tonne".

Could you help me out?

Comment: From the above it seems, you are trying to predict the change(delta) in ethylene spot (delta y) using changes in predictor (delta x). Since the `fcst` denotes predicted change in spot price which is a dimensionless number since it is result of ratio of spot prices expressed in `(USD/tonne)/(USD/tonne)`. If you really do need to express output in `USD/tonne`, you need a base value(current value) and expression as `base_value *(1+ fcst+-sd)` where sd is std deviation of `fcst`

Comment: @Osssan Thank you very much! I will try to plug that in a vector in order to get the final result and plot it.

Comment: @Osssan Sorry to back only now. I got these outputs for "WINTER_DEGREE_DAYS_US":

Comment: @Osssan Sorry to back only now. I got these predicted values for **WINTER_DEGREE_DAYS_US**: 
     `FCST`
     `-0.98177987`
     `0.43288647`
     `-0.8947595`

When I began with the model, I applied the following procedure to lei it stationary:
     `diff(log(data[,"US_WINTER_DEGREE_DAYS"]))`

So, the bottom line is: in order to put these output (predicted) values to the same level, should I apply 
`(base_value)*(1 + exp(fcst) + - sd)`?